# 7-Zip Problem for windows mobile

Tags: c#, .net, windows-mobile, compact-framework, 7zip

i am trying to build the 7zip code, which i can use in my windows mobile project..
does any one know how to build 7zip code and use the same in windows mobile application..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have looked at the 7zip's website [here](http://www.7-zip.org/) and to quote what they said '7-Zip works in Windows 7 / Vista / XP / 2008 / 2003 / 2000 / NT / ME / 98. There is a port of the command line version to Linux/Unix.' A quick glance at the source code shows that there is x86 assembly involved to achieve a compression algorithm. This could explain why you could not port it across to Windows Mobile as the processor is not x86.

There is a folder within the source code called `\Asm\x86\7zCrcT8U.asm' so obviously does not target the processor in which Windows Mobile run on.

I did a quick google to see if there is indeed a version that is suitable for the Windows Mobile device. But, [this](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=417019) could be the one you're looking for?

Hope this helps,
Best regards,
Tom.

Comment: Hey Thanks for response, i need to create .maff extension(it is an web archive which Mozilla support) this is the link http://maf.mozdev.org/maff-specification.html, but in this look at "ZIP implementation" part, i tried open source ziplib for mobile "http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/".. i dont no how to set the stuff mentioned by mozilla.. can u please help me out in this

Comment: @Solitaire: Have you looked at some pkware's zip implementation either commercial or open source? I have had a quick glance at pkware.com's site http://www.pkware.com/software-developer-tools-margin/data-compression-library, it's proprietary. Judging from the spec, that there could well be assembly code involved. I think you are stuck at this stage, but then again, PKWare's zip algorithm is compatible with Winzip, and 7Zip can handle it also. Maybe use a tar/gzip implementation (ICSharp.ZipLib implementation here..http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SharpZipLib/ Other than recompiling it.

Comment: @tommieb75: Hey do u have any idea about how to build icsharp.ziplib source for compact framework..
the source code they have given is for desktop,, i tried by downloading prebuilt binaries for windows mobile.. worked well..
i am not getting how to build source to get them ?

Comment: @Solitaire: Simply create a blank project/solution targetting the Compact Framework, then add in the ICSharpCode.ZipLib solution i.e. folders and files into it and rebuild. Make sure you do know what is the layout of the structure for the desktop solution. Does this make sense?

Answer (score 0):

7-zip doesn't work on windows mobile check the [main page](http://www.7-zip.org/)

Answer (score 0):

If you need to get the algorithm to work under another OS (or processor architecture) than you should take a look into the [LZMA SDK](http://www.7-zip.org/sdk.html). Here you got the algorithm to en- or decode a 7zip file in C, C++, C# or Java.

With these you should be able to create a library for the ARM. And if you make a little more investigations into the sources from 7zip itself you should be capable to link these to parts together.